# Custom Observer with Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: javascript, ios, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have data in a Firebase database which I currently observe from an iOS app. I would like to create my own `observe` function using Firebase Functions which pulls from a separate database before returning the data.

Is there any way to recreate my own version of Firebase API's observe method? This is what I have so far

```
exports.onChildAdded = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {

    var ref = firebase.database().ref("data");
    ref.on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
        console.log(snapshot.key);

        var allData;
        allData.firebase = snapshot;

        //pull from other database
        allData.other = otherDatabaseData;

        response.send(allData);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 2):

That isn't really a thing you can do with Cloud Functions for Firebase.  HTTP functions are required to finish work quickly (timeout one minute by default, 9 minutes max by special configuration) and return a single response to the client.  You can't listen persistently to a particular location in the database using `on()`.  You can, however, query the database a single time with `once()` and do something with the result.  But that's obviously not the same as `"child_added"` listeners.

Doing this will require you to run your own custom server that allows you to have long-running processes under your control.

Comment: That's unfortunate, I guess i'll just have to make two requests on the device side.